# Как специально сделать вылет игры на Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Надо сделать что бы при входе в триггер игра либо вылетала с ошибкой, либо был краш. Возможно ли это как то сделать?

Comment: Рекурсия вам в помощь - `void F(){F();} F();`

Comment: Но не советую попробовать его в editor-е

Comment: Либо безконечный цикл. `While (True) { Debug.Log("Happy End =D"); }`

Comment: А собственно зачем именно с ошибкой? Вы же можете реализовать выключение игры командой Application.Quit()

Comment: `int i = 0; i = 1 / i;`

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать просто выход из игры, благодаря Application.Quit. Это самый правильный способ. Если вы хотите ИМЕННО ВЫЛЕТ, могу рекомендовать бесконечный цикл. Самое простое решение)